Do the GraphQL APIs work in LWCs running inside a Digital Experience?
We have this note in an LWC written 4 months ago:

// Note: documented to not work in Digital Experiences in 2024.

that uses:
import { gql, graphql } from 'lightning/uiGraphQLApi';

But I now can't find documentation that confirms that. I assume this limitation is still in place? Any information on this - including a link to the appropriate limitations page - appreciated.

It certainly was documented so that comment was accurate at a point in time - it isn't the case any more.
The document no longer mentions it (neither in this limitation which it used to). I can say I've used graphql in Aura sites for a couple releases successfully now.
Even though the release note is a bit vague - LWR Sites support was delivered in Winter '25 which allowed them to note it's now fully supported in Experience Cloud sites here.

lightning/uiGraphQLApi
The GraphQL wire adapter is now supported in Experience Cloud sites.

